# Status and Future of Silverlight Toolkit

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

After completing a small hobby project which leaned only moderately on the SL toolkit, I couldn't help but notice a lot of rough edges (a lot).  The most recent version seems to be from April 2010 (!), and the forum for posting bugs seems to be abandoned.  Maybe that last point was an exaggeration, but only slightly.

My (serious) question is, has anyone from the SL team stated what the future of the toolkit is?  Is it being rolled into Silverlight 5?  Has the toolkit simply been converted/upgraded to SL 5, and will be re-released (with some new polish) when SL5 drops?

Any info anyone has would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

For completeness, I'd like to note that [Microsoft is taking down the Silverlight.net website](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/89-net/5179-microsoft-closes-silverlightnet.html).  It seems all but certain now that, as assumed by many previously, Silverlight is headed for the graveyard.  I'd be shocked if there were any future additions to the Silverlight Toolkit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Silverlight Toolkit is, and will remain, a place for Microsoft to provide useful tools and controls for helping our customers develop their applications.  Recently, our focus has been on the Silverlight 5 Beta, but we do expect to release updates, including an update for Silverlight 5 towards the end of our release.

EDIT:

Thought I should point out that I am the current (as of 6/2011) Program Manager for the Silverlight ToolKit.

EDIT #2:

We just released a Silverlight 5 Toolkit (for the SL5 RC) here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/74436

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jason.  The toolkit looks like it's had some amazing, solid work done on it, and was then dropped; that's why I asked the question.  I'll look forward to seeing your forthcoming releases.

Comment: No problem, if you want to try something pretty amazing right now, take a look at the logging part of this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2011/03/30/preview-drop-3-of-enterprise-library-silverlight-integration-pack.aspx

Comment: It looks like there's some slick stuff coming for SL5.  I'm really glad to hear that there's not much truth behind the chatter I'm hearing about Microsoft's heart not being behind SL.

Comment: Thx for the update.  Will there be any updates to the toolkit for Silverlight 4?  ie. if I have an app using SL 4, will I be able to use any of the new stuff in the next release of the toolkit?

Comment: @Joe, that is still being evaluated right now.  I will update this when I find something out.

Comment: The 1000th view notification for this question reminded me it exists.  So at this point I think we can all agree it's dead :)